# Configured a static ip but it didn't take effect immediately

Tags: network-manager, ifconfig, static-ip

So I configured a static ip connection on the GUI but it didn't seems to take effect when I check with ifconfig. I think if I restart the computer, it'll take effect but it sounds "overkill" for an ip change.

I read about network manager reset on CLI but then I'd have done the whole thing on CLI. There must be some way on the GUI?

Also, SHOULD I do ifconfig or through network manager? ifconfig feels more "reliable" with ifdown/ifup. It just clicks. However will I break any relying service using ifconfig?

Comment: Restart always works, though

Comment: Anyway to restart connection on GUI? Without restarting the computer? If not is there any reason behind it not taking effecting immediately? I think since network manager aims to be a more user friendly addition, requiring restart or CLI for ip change seems counterproductive.

Comment: Don't know about GUI but an `ifdown [interface]` then `ifup [interface]` should do it.

Comment: From what I understand ifdown/ifup use ifconfig and would disable network manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you modify a "connection" (in NetworkManager's speak) which is currently activated in a device, those changes don't take effect immediately. Well, your UI could implement it in a way to apply them right away, but they don't.

You have to re-activate the connection, like
  `nmcli connection up $NAME`
or whatever your preferred UI is.

You don't have to restart NetworkManager. Also, you usually don't use ifconfig with NetworkManager together.

Comment: I wish I could give more than one upvote!